# What is a C extension?

Tags: c++, c

What is the meaning of 'C extension'?

Comment: A C extension is an extended string on a double bass, allowing the musician to play a slightly lower range, down to a C rather than down to a E, making it easier to play 'cello parts.

Comment: Does @fredley's comment mean the question needs to migrate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://www.mjbl.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8&Itemid=8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An extension in C is a feature supported by a C compiler that is not described (permitted, mandated) by the C standard.  (And similarly for C++, since the question is tagged like that.)

For example, GCC allows you to define a function within the body of another function; standard C does not.  That is a C extension.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the .c extension on source code files?  That just means that the code within the file is (supposed to be) C.  It's different from the .cpp extension in that a .cpp extension indicates C++ code in the file.

---

*Hijacking GreenMatt's answer*

#### Possible extensions for C++ source code

On MacOS X, `man g++` lists 7 possible/acceptable extensions for C++ source code:

- `file.cc`
- `file.cp`
- `file.cxx`
- `file.cpp`
- `file.CPP`
- `file.c++`
- `file.C`

It also mentions `file.i` is a file that does not need pre-processing - it contains the output from the C preprocessor.

Comment: Unless the extension for a C++ file is `.C` or `.cxx`, both of which are, or were, quite widely used.

Comment: cpp stands for C preprocessor. May be it was Microsoft with its Visual Studio who first started using .cpp for C++ files, which is wrong of course and confused a lot of people.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler:  Thanks for the comment.  I've not done much C++ work, but when I did, we used .c for C and .cpp for C++.

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin:  It's always been my impression that .cpp was for C++ code.  Can you cite a reference stating that cpp = C preprocessor?  BTW: The work I mentioned in my comment toward Jonathan was done long ago (the early 1990's) using Borland compilers, which (IIRC) were much more widely used then than Microsoft's.

Comment: @GreenMatt: `man cpp`.  But it's never occurred to me to use `.cpp` as a file extension for C preprocessor output; I've always associated it with C++, ever since using it in Turbo C++ in high school.

Comment: I think probably `.cpp` is the most widely used suffix these days; however, a decade ago, it was anything but clear cut.  The `.C` was the first to fall by the wayside - Windows (and MacOS X) have case-insensitive file systems, so it doesn't work there.  The idea behind `.cxx` is the it looks like the `.c++` except that the plusses rotated 45º.  I'm not quite sure why `.c++` was not used, but it was likely related to something mildly eccentric like "make does not interpret suffix rules unless the suffix is alphanumeric and `.c++` clearly isn't".

Comment: @dan04: on at least some systems, if the C compiler writes the C preprocessor output to a file, the extension given it is `.i`.

Comment: @Jonathan: on Linux .cc is often used for C++ files.

Comment: @Max: I'd forgotten that one!

Comment: @dan04:  Thanks for the suggestion.  Obviously I was thinking "C extension" in a different way ...

Comment: @Jonathan: DOS used to not allow `+` in filenames, apparently because it interfered with the `COPY source1+source2 dest` syntax for concatenating files.

Comment: @dan04 - ahah! There was method in the madness.  Thanks.